# How to manage node-mysql database connections?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hie, I am building a job recruitment app with NodeJS express framework and `express-handlebars` as my Rendering Engine. The problem is that when I post a new Job listing and save it to my `node-mysql` database and then refresh the jobs list page, The UI doesn't include the newly added post until after I restart my nodejs server. This is obviously not Ideal in production. How can I rectify this? Below is my current problematic solution:

Database connection :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pass',
  database:'myjobsdb'
});

connection.connect(err=> {
  console.log('Oops!, Failed to connect to the database.');
})


module.exports = connection;
```

And this is the file that fetch these listings

```
const connection = require('./database')


function fetchAll( searchObj,callback ){
    let sql = `SELECT *, jobs.id AS job_id FROM jobs JOIN companies JOIN accounts JOIN countries WHERE  jobs.status != 'Deleted' AND jobs.company = companies.email AND companies.email = accounts.email_address AND countries.zip = companies.country `;

    if(searchObj.location != '' && searchObj.location != null && searchObj.location != undefined){
        sql += ` AND (jobs.location LIKE '%${searchObj.location}%' OR countries.country_name LIKE '%${searchObj.location}%') `
    }
    if(searchObj.keyword != '' && searchObj.keyword != null && searchObj.keyword != undefined){
        sql += ` AND (jobs.job_description LIKE '%${searchObj.keyword}%' OR jobs.job_title LIKE '%${searchObj.keyword}%') `
    }

    sql += ' ORDER BY jobs.id DESC'
    console.log(sql);
    connection.query(sql, (err, results)=>{
        if(err){
            callback([])
        }else{
            
            callback(results)
        }
    })
}

module.exports = {fetchAll}
```

I import this file into the script that handles job listing routes and dynamically render the results via express-handlebars into a list. Here is how:

```
module.exports = (router)=>{
    const account = require("../account")
    const jobs = require('../jobs')
    const tasks = require('../tasks')
    const messages = require('../messages')
    const freelancers = require('../freelancers')
    let jobs_list
    
    jobs.fetchAll({'location':'','keyword':''}, response=>{
        jobs_list = response
    })

    router.get(['/','/home'],(req,res)=>{
        //console.log(`Jobs returned : ${JSON.stringify(jobs_list)}`)
        if(req.session.username && req.session.username != null && req.session.username != ''){
            messages.ComposeMessages(req.session.username, response => {
                let msg = response.data
                account.get(req.session.username, req.session.acc_type, response=>{
                    let mydata = response.data
                    freelancers.get(response => {
                        freelancers_list = response
                            res.render('home',{
                                'title':'Home',
                                'footer':true,
                                'jobs':jobs_list,
                                'freelancer':freelancers_list,
                                'messages':msg,
                                'session':true,
                                'mydata':mydata,
                                'acc_type':req.session.acc_type
                            })
                    })
                })
            })
            
        }else{
            freelancers.get(response => {
                freelancers_list = response
                    res.render('home',{
                        'title':'Home',
                        'footer':true,
                        'jobs':jobs_list,
                        'freelancer':freelancers_list,
                        'session':false,
                        'acc_type':req.session.acc_type
                    })
                })
        }        
    })

    

    return router
};
```

Comment: It seems like `fetchAll()` is being executed only during application startup instead of on every call to the jobs list page. Could you, please, include also code of the endpoint?

Comment: Also, I see that `searchObj` is used as part of SQL query and I hope that this data doesn't come from a user, otherwise, the application might be vulnerable to SQL-injections.

Comment: Yes @SlavaSemushin, that was the problem. My implementation was a bit dumb, I was only calling it once on application startup. Now i've got a handle on it. Thanx

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the security threat, i'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of why you see a stale data and have to restart an application is because `fetchAll()` is being executed only during startup instead of on every call to the jobs list page. Move it into a controller method in order to fix the issue.